# Invocar metodo touchInside via programação em SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Boa noite pessoal, minha duvida pode ser simples para muitos mais estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade para resolver o mesmo. Vamos lá !!!

Eu criei um botão(UIButton) e gostaria de saber como eu invoco uma ação quando o mesmo é clicado via programação.

Desde já grato pela atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIButton extende UIControl, que usa o conceito de *target/action* para o tratamento de eventos. *Action* é basicamente um método que será disparado quando o evento ocorrer. *Target* é o objeto que recebe a mensagem, isto é, que deve implementar a *action*.

No exemplo abaixo eu adicionei um botão no storyboard e conectei ao outlet. Então no método `viewDidLoad` defini o método a ser chamado (buttonClicked - *action*), na instância do view controller (self - *target*). O último parâmetro é o tipo de evento a ser detectado. No caso utilizei TouchUpInside, que é o clique regular.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        println("Botão pressionado")
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @RafaelLeao, era isso mesmo que eu estava procurando.